# "message": "Trying to get property 'secret' of non-object", "exception": "ErrorException",

Tags: laravel, postman, laravel-passport

[image]

> "message": "Trying to get property 'secret' of non-object",
> "exception": "ErrorException",
> "file": "C:\xampp\htdocs\project_laravel\sample\vendor\laravel\passport\src\PersonalAccessTokenFactory.php",
> "line": 96,

this is the error i get?

Comment: Please post your code in the question not as a screenshot. Also, you are using `$client->secret` but the error seems to indicate that `$client` is not an object. How are you calling that method?

Answer (score 0):

### If you are still having this issue, you can try the steps below.

The first thing is to run the `php artisan passport:client --personal`.

Inside your database table **oauth_clients**, under column ***name***, look for **Laravel Personal Access Client**.

Copy the `secret` beside `Laravel Personal Access Client`.

Open `AuthServiceProvider`, then paste the secret inside the **boot** method where the `CLIENT_SECRET` is below:

```
Passport::personalAccessClientSecret(config('CLIENT_SECRET'));
```

And don't forget to also add the ID of the secret from your database.

```
Passport::personalAccessClientId(config('ID'));
```

Note: Use the quote along with the **ID** and **CLIENT_SECRET** as config() is expected to get a string.